# jQuery tooltip class not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have some functions called by onclick events, which works excelent. They send a $.post() request and on success I retrieve the (data) returned by the php file called in the post() request.

My wierd problem is that the jQuery ToolTip plugin doesn't read the css stylesheet after the ajax call, partially. Yeap, that's why I said wierd.

I customized the tooltip to be black, three rounded corners and small, white text, and it looks great, but after the ajax call, the corners and the size of the text are changed (all corners rounded and bigger text). The tooltip works but looks strange. 
Here's some code:

css declarations

```
#aToolTip {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 50000;
```

}

```
#aToolTip .aToolTipContent {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.defaultTheme {
border:2px solid #444;
background:rgba(102,102,102,1);
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
text-shadow:0 0 3px #666;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:11px;
margin:0;
padding:3px 6px;

-moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
-khtml-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;
border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 0;

-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #111; /* for Firefox 3.5+ */
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #111; /* for Safari and Chrome */
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #111; /* for Safari and Chrome */
```

}

```
.defaultTheme #aToolTipCloseBtn {
    display:block;
    height:12px;
    width:18px;
    background:url(../images/closeBtn.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    outline:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-30px;
    margin:2px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

head declarations of course

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/atooltip.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
```

javascript functions

```
function addCul(culId, pId) {
    var value = culId.value;
    $.post("post.php", {
        addColId: value,
        prodId: pId
    }, function(data) {
        $('.culori').html(data);
        $('.normalTip').tooltip();
    })
}
```

And there are the images with what I see.

[image: Normal tooltip]

[image: Tooltip without complete css]

Hope someone can figure this out, 'cause is anoying.

Edit.
Got your point, just added CSS markup, can't really add all the html, but it's a simple reference.
I have a `<button onclick="function()"></button>` wich works fine. The jquery post works fine as well, but the tooltip just looks exactly how you see it in the pictures. Can't explain why it's keeping the colors, but not the text size. And this is happening after executing the jQuery post and reload the data into the target div.

Comment: where do you customize the tooltip??

Comment: We cannot really help without seeing any HTML markup nor CSS rules. Provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue. BTW, inspect element and check what's going wrong regarding styling